# Authenticating an app installation in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: authentication

I want to install an app within the Ubuntu software center. When I click on the "install" button, I am prompted to authenticate. I use what I think is the correct authentication but Ubuntu won't take it. How do I disable the authentication, or change the password so I can authenticate?

Comment: What does the error message say ? because I think you're not using the right authentication or policykit-1-gnome is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed anything manually, the password should be the same one you use to log on to your account.  You must have root rights otherwise you cannot install anything on a Linux system.  Disabling that password is definitely not recommended.